# Browse and Select unsupported files

Tags: finder, safari, google-chrome, web-browsing

A website is asking me to upload pdf documents but once I browse to upload all the files (pdf format) they are greyed out and not selectable.

I have tried Chrome, Safari, Firefox but there is no change in the behaviour.

It's not only one pdf, in which case I would think the file is corrupted or something.

[image: details]

Comment: a quick request, what is the web site you are using?

Comment: Its RWTH University online application

Comment: Its first time I am facing this after 6-7 years working with OS X. Link : https://movein.campus.rwth-aachen.de/movein/portal/studyportal.php?_language=en

Comment: Thank you so much, its so troublesome as you have to fill up a total new application...

Comment: Guess what, I just drag the file and dropped it on the "uploadfile" button and it worked :D Tnx to both of you :)

Comment: Great, now you can go and STUDY, not party.

Comment: hahahah, wish me luck, I just applied for Master :)

Comment: @Robuust please write your answer so I can mark it as answered. The reputation must go to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least a fix for this in Chrome will be dragging and dropping the file to the fileupload control on the page.

**Drag** the file to "Choose file - no file selected" and **drop** it there, it will be ready for upload.